# Angular JS math with values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to gather values using angularJS and do some math with them. I have tried the following but did not work, I am very new at angularJS and I have a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D4gse/) (I dont know how to get angularJS working on JSFiddle)

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="WizardController">
<wizard on-before-step-change="log(event)" on-step-changing="log(event)" on-after-step-change="log(event)">

    <step title="stepOne">
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.a" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.b" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.c" />
        {{totalNumber}}
    </step>

</wizard>    
</body>



var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('WizardController', ['$scope', function($scope){

  $scope.user = { };
  $scope.totalNumber = $scope.user.a * $scope.user.b * 50 + $scope.user.c - $scope.user.a;

}]);
```

if I do $scope.totalNumber = $scope.user, and then {{totalNumber}} i get this returned: {"a":"1"} (if I have `<input type="text" ng-model="user.a">`) but when I do $scope.user.a nothing displays this is very frusturating

Comment: The answer below is probably it, but as a further tip, you can use type="number" rather than type="text" to make these fields numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to Angular, start with [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DChu9/2/).  It shows very simply how to load Angular (check the left sidebar) and how to work with numbers from the scope.

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="num1" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="num2" />
    {{ total() }}
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.num1 = 10;
    $scope.num2 = 23;

    $scope.total = function() {
        return $scope.num1 * $scope.num2;
    }
});
```

Comment: it makes no sense why $scope.totalNumber = $scope.user works, but not $scope.user.a

Comment: `$scope.totalNumber` is a primitive value so it can bind to the scope right away.  `$scope.user = {}` is an object.  `$scope.user` can bind to the scope, but `$scope.user.a` does not exist when the scope is created, so there is no reference to bind.  That being said, using *objects* is [recommended by Angular](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) but you still need to understand how to use them.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is generally case-sensitive. You probably wanted this in your HTML:

```
{{ totalNumber }}
```

Comment: OP: This is correct, you will need to match the case of your scope.  However your Fiddle is overly complex and has a number of issues that are keeping it from working regardless of whether you include Angular properly and update this binding.

Answer (score 1):

**1 way:**

Remove: `{{totalNumber}}`
Put: `{{user.a * user.b * 50 + user.c - user.a}}`

**2 way like [Terry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/803739/terry) said:**
script:
`$scope.totalNumber = function(){` 
`return  $scope.user.a * $scope.user.b * 50 + $scope.user.c - $scope.user.a;`
    }
html:
`{{totalNumber()}}`